# My HTML5 video tag isn't working and I cant figure out why

Tags: html, video

I'm relatively new to this. But as far as I can see there isn't anything wrong. Im using the latest version of Chrome, so that shouldn't be the issue. Nothings disabled that would break it.

```html
<video width =500px height =500px  controls>
        <source src="Video/GIMPTutorial.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

[Screenshot of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6AGP.png)

[Screenshot of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt0NP.png)

Answer (score 0):

check your link of video first . Is it working properly .As reference of this w3school tag is correct but link is not correct.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

Your width and height of tag is also incorrect use 
width="your desired width" 
and 
height=""
not use px at the end of value .
I hope this help you alot